# Magento custom controller action does not render design

Tags: magento

people. i have a problem. I have an action in my custom module, that creates customer.
There is a code:

```
class SeosClub_BusinessCategory_CustomerController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

public function createAction(){

    $requestData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    if(!$requestData['id'] || !$requestData['activation_code']){
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Request data invalid');
    }

    $company = Mage::getModel('businesscategory/company')->load($requestData['id']);
    if (!$company->getId()){
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Your company does not exist');
    }
    if($company->getCustomerId()){
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice($this->__('Customer already created. Forgot password?'));
        $this->_redirect('customer/account/forgotpassword/');
        return;
    }

    $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load('Companies', 'customer_group_code');;

    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());
    $customer->setData('group_id', $group->getId());

    $customer->setFirstname($company->getName());
    $customer->setLastname($this->__('Unknown'));
    $customer->setEmail($company->getEmail());
    $customer->setPassword(Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(8));
    try{
        $customer->save();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
        $company->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        $company->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Account was created succefully'));
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
       Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    }


    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();

}
```

}

I have also installed theme on my magento. But, when i open the page, it renderes base magento theme, not my installed theme.
If i comment code from `if($company->getCustomerId())` to `$this->loadLayout();` (not including $this->loadLayout();), it renderes correct theme.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to fix that i needed to send customer email after rendering layout.

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer mode in magento. Uncomment display_errors in index.php. You should see some errors, since you have:

```
$company = Mage::getModel('businesscategory/company')->load($requestData['id']);
```

$requestData['id'] might not be set here, because your if condition is not ending the processing of the method. So further in the code you might not have $company and you call functions on null.

Check if $company is an object.

I think it renders the default theme becuse you have errors.

Comment: Enabled. No errors. `$company` - it's an obgect. `$requestData['id']` defined. Everything is working except design.

Comment: And further down your code? $company->getCustomerId() ?

Comment: i told you, that everything is working except of design. when customer is created, it sets customer_id to defined company. And it works correctly.

Comment: Well you say that commenting that piece of code shows the right theme., so something wrong must happen between those 2 pieces of code. You can also turn on the Template hints from Admin

Comment: Ok, i've found, that the problem is in `$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();`. How can i send that e-mail and not brake design? To send after rendering design?